# Overload operators to work with class objects?

Tags: c++, class, overloading

How can I modify the following code in such way I don't need to repeat `f2=11;
f3=12;` in the main function. The code is for overloading the most common operators.

```
class FLOAT{
    private:
        float x;
    public:
        FLOAT(){    x=0.0;  }
        void setFloat(float f)      {   x=f;    }
        float getFloat()            {   return x;};
        FLOAT operator+(FLOAT obj)  {x=x+obj.x; return *this;};
        FLOAT operator-(FLOAT obj)  {x=x-obj.x; return *this;};
        FLOAT operator*(FLOAT obj)  {x=x*obj.x; return *this;};
        FLOAT operator/(FLOAT obj)  {x=x/obj.x; return *this;};
        FLOAT& operator=(const FLOAT& obj)  {this->x=obj.x; return *this;   };
        FLOAT& operator=(const float& y)    {this->x=y; return *this;   };
};

int main() {
    FLOAT f,f2,f3;
    f2=11;
    f3=12;

    f=f3-f2;
    cout<<"f3-f2 ="<<f.getFloat()<<endl;


    f2=11;
    f3=12;
    f=f3+f2;
    cout<<"f3+f2 ="<<f.getFloat()<<endl;

    f2=11;
    f3=12;
    f=f3*f2;
    cout<<"f3*f2 ="<<f.getFloat()<<endl;

    f2=11;
    f3=12;
    f=f3/f2;
    cout<<"f3/f2 ="<<f.getFloat()<<endl;

    system("pause"); // to pause console screen
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: The short summary is that you wrote operators that behave almost like +=, -=, *=, and /=. TO get what you want, you need operators that behave like +, -, *, and /.

Comment: Indentation. **Please.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Oli's answer pretty much says you what *minimal* thing you need to do in order to make your code work. However, I see (and I know even @Oli sees) that your implementation of the class has many flaws.

Since you've implemented `FLOAT`, I'm explaining you the implementation of `Double` (the implementation of `FLOAT` would be similar).

```
class Double {
  double data;
public:
  Double (double p=0.0) : data(p){}
  double value() { return data; }
  Double & operator+=(Double const & other) 
  {
         data += other.data; 
         return *this;
  }
  Double & operator-=(Double const & other) 
  {
         data -= other.data; 
         return *this;
  }
  //...
};
```

Note that you don't need to implement `operator=(Double const&)` and `Double(Double const&)`. The compiler generated ones would be enough. Since the constructor takes one argument of type `double`, you don't need to implement `operator=(double const &)` also. The compiler generated copy-semantics, along with the constructor, would take care of that.

Now see this,

```
//implement operator+ and operator- as non-member functions
Double operator+(Double a,  Double const & b)
{
    a += b; //a is local copy, so we can change it
    return a;
}
Double operator-(Double a,  Double const & b)
{
    a -= b; //a is local copy, so we can change it
    return a;
}
```

Note that I've implemented `operator+` and `operator-`  in terms of `operator+=` and `operator-=` respectively.

Similarly, you can implement `operator/=` and `operator*=`  as member functions, and then implement `operator/` and `operator*` in terms of the them!

Answer (score 2):

Your operators should create a new instance; they shouldn't be modifying themselves (in fact, they should be declared `const` to prevent this).

e.g.:

```
FLOAT operator+(FLOAT obj) const
{
    FLOAT tmp;
    tmp.setFloat(x + obj.x);
    return tmp;
}
```

Note there are much more idiomatic ways of defining operator overloads (e.g. defining `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`, and defining a constructor that takes a `float`).  But the above should suffice.

Comment: Adding a `FLOAT(float a_x)` constructor would improve this: `FLOAT operator+(FLOAT obj) const { return FLOAT(x + obj.x); }`